# Angular is it necessary to unsubscribe from this.activatedRoute subscriptions

Tags: angular, rxjs

My code:

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    // do stuff
  })

  this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data: any) => {
    // do stuff
  })

}
```

My question is ... do I need to unsubscribe from these in ngOnDestroy?

As a matter of habit I always unsub but not sure if it is necessary here.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you don't need to unsubscribe from route observables

From the [***Documentation***](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#observable-parammap-and-component-reuse)

> When subscribing to an observable in a component, you almost always unsubscribe when the component is destroyed.
>
> However, ActivatedRoute observables are among the exceptions because ActivatedRoute and its observables are insulated from the Router itself. The Router destroys a routed component when it is no longer needed. This means all the component's members will also be destroyed, including the injected ActivatedRoute and the subscriptions to its Observable properties.
>
> The Router does not complete any Observable of the ActivatedRoute so any finalize or complete blocks will not run. If you need to handle something in a finalize, you still need to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy. You also have to unsubscribe if your observable pipe has a delay with code you do not want to run after the component is destroyed.

Comment: FYI the docs say this but as of Angular's latest release, it still doesn't seem to always be true.  Not unsbcribing from ActivatedRoute caused a lot of memory leaks in my applications.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather unsubscribe all then control the exceptions. Seems easier to maintain.

Something like this

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        // do stuff
      }));

    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data: any) => {
        // do stuff
      }));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach((subscription: Subscription) => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
  }
```

Please see the example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unsubscribing-then-all?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: check https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0  Point 3 for a much cleaner way to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 1):

For activated routes observable is an exception, because `The ActivatedRoute and its observables are insulated from the Router itself. The Router destroys a routed component when it is no longer needed and the injected ActivatedRoute dies with it.`

Source: [Angular Doc](https://angular.io/guide/router#observable-parammap-and-component-reuse)

Answer (score 1):

Normally when your component destroys, all the subscribed observables get unsubscribe automatically with few exceptions. But activatedRoute is not one of it. When router exit from a routed component it will destroy the component along with the injected `activatedRoute`