# Do you need to unsubscribe from a subscription to router params in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router, angular2-observables, rxjs-observables

When you subscribe to query params in a component, do you need to unsubscribe? I'm trying to avoid a memory leak.

**Subscription with variable for `unsubscribe()`**

```
  subscription$: Subscription

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription$ = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
      (params: any): void => {
        // ... Do stuff here ...
      }
    )
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscription$ !== undefined || this.subscription$ !== null) {
      this.subscription$.unsubscribe()
    }
  }
```

**Subscription without variable for `unsubscribe()`**

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
      (params: any): void => {
        // ... Do stuff here ...
      }
    )
  }
```

**Which one is a better solution?**

Comment: The `ActivatedRoute` is nulled out when the route is destroyed, so there is no need to manually unsubscribe.

Comment: @Liam gently asking you to provide more information about the `queryParams` deprecations since those links u have provided have no reference for neither `queryParams` vs. `depr` for example https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#removed-apis

Answer (score 3):

The ActivatedRoute unsubscribes all of its subscribers when the component is destroyed.

You can look the doc: https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#observable-parammap-and-component-reuse

> When subscribing to an observable in a component, you almost always
> arrange to unsubscribe when the component is destroyed.
>
> There are a few exceptional observables where this is not necessary.
> The ActivatedRoute observables are among the exceptions.
>
> The ActivatedRoute and its observables are insulated from the Router
> itself. The Router destroys a routed component when it is no longer
> needed and the injected ActivatedRoute dies with it.

Answer (score -1):

You can found this question for reference

[Angular is it necessary to unsubscribe from this.activatedRoute subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52006017/angular-is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-this-activatedroute-subscriptions/52006800)

but i would say unsubscribing whenever you have subscribed to something is always a good practice. Their are various ways for unsubscribing we can do that just using only one  extra variable for subscription

I always prefer to unsubscribe in this situation as well